# Search "[" or "]" inside a table using SQL command

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

In an SQL table I have following columns

```
id, title, content
```

And I would like to search text inside title or content having "**[**" or "**]**".

What will be the SQL command to fetch such kind of data?

(edit: removed "efficient")

(added)
As per "rsbarro"

I have tried and my findings are:

If I try for

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%[%'
```

returns  0 row.

If I try for

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%]%'
```

returns number of rows.

Comment: There is no any efficient way to do that

Comment: Are you just looking to return rows that contain [ or ] in the title or are you trying to extract the text between the brackets?

Comment: return rows that contain [ or ] in the title/content

Comment: @Hoque See the update to my answer. That statement will return any row with a [ or a ] in title or content, regardless of the order in which they appear. If you can always count on [ coming before ], then you can reduce the `WHERE` clause to one `LIKE` operator for each field using the pattern `'%[%]%'`.

Comment: @rsbarro I have tried with SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%[%' --but it returns 0 row though the title contains "[".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples above are failing for like matching because [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) offers a single character match option with [].

```
Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
```

To actually match a `[`, you will need to embed it in a pair of brackets

```
;
WITH DEMO (Title) AS
(
    SELECT 'Where are you [ I am here]'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'WHO ARE YOU'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'asdafasfa][asdfadfasdfasdfa'
)
SELECT 
    D.* 
FROM 
    DEMO D 
WHERE 
    D.Title LIKE '%[[]%' 
    OR D.Title LIKE '%[]]%'
```

Returns

```
Where are you [ I am here]
asdafasfa][asdfadfasdfasdfa
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `LIKE` operator, but remember if you are searching for a `[` you need to escape it as `[[]` (see @billinkc's answer for an explanation on the escaping, or check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and look for the section "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals"). The statement:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%[[]%'
```

will search for any record in `MyTable` where `Title` contains a `[`. The `%` is a wildcard character.

I'm not exactly sure from the question what you are trying to find, but if you want to search for a title containing both brackets (i.e., '??[match]??'), try:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%[[]%]%'
```

**EDIT**
If you are trying to match either [ or ] in title or in content, the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE 
      Content LIKE '%[[]%' OR Content LIKE '%]%' OR
      Title LIKE '%[[]%' OR Title LIKE '%]%'
```

This query would probably not be terribly efficient if you have a table with a large number of rows.

Comment: SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%[%' -does not give any result.

Comment: But SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Title LIKE '%]%' -return rows

Comment: @Hoque I updated my answer in light of @billinkc's answer. He's right, you need to escape the `[`, sorry I missed it initially.

Answer (score 2):

In Sql `[` is a special character and where `[[]` means `[`, so the below Sql query will work accordingly.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (Title LIKE '%[[]%' OR content LIKE '%[[]%')
                          OR (Title LIKE '%]%' OR content LIKE '%]%')
```

Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)for more details.